# How to select an element from NodeList in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodelist

I wanted to make a food order app, and try to make the quantity buttons like this with my own code: 
 https://css-tricks.com/examples/InputNumberIncrementer/

I struggled with the results. There is an input which will set the quantity once `incButtons` or `decButtons` is clicked.
But when I click a button, all the inputs change. How do I fix it, if I want the input to change only  on the clicked button, not set to all inputs?

this is my source code :

```js
let incButton = document.querySelectorAll('.inc');
let decButton = document.querySelectorAll('.dec');

// Increment Button
for (let i = 0; i < incButton.length; i++){
    
    incButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        
    // show the decButton when quantity > 1
    decButton[i].style.display = 'inline';
    // increment the quantity when incButton clicked
    for (let i = 0; i < incButton.length; i++){
        let inputField = document.querySelectorAll('.quantityNumber');
        
      if(incButton) {
        let newVal = parseInt(inputField[i].value) + 1;
        inputField[i].value = newVal;
        
        console.log('Quantity +1 added');
       } 
    }
});
};
// Decrement Button
for (let i = 0; i < decButton.length; i++) {
    decButton[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    
        let inputField = document.querySelectorAll('.quantityNumber');
        for (let i = 0; i < inputField.length; i++) {
            // if decButton is clicked and quantitiy >= 2 decrement it
            if (decButton[i] && inputField[i].value >= 2) {
                let newVal = parseInt(inputField[i].value) - 1;
                inputField[i].value = newVal;
        
                console.log('Quantity -1 reduced');
            }
            // hide the decButton when quantity is 1
            if (inputField[i].value == 1) {
                decButton[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<div class="quantity">
    <button class="dec">-</button>
    <input type="text" class="quantityNumber" value="1">
    <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="quantity">
    <button class="dec">-</button>
    <input type="text" class="quantityNumber" value="1">
    <button class="inc">+</button>
</div>
```

Please help me to solve this, and thank you before for the questions :)

Comment: Why is there a loop? Use `this` (check the documentation of [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for a "how to")

Comment: `if(incButton) { ... }` - The condition will always evaluate as `true` because `incButton` is always an object. And an object is always [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)